# Linear model with categorical dependent variable

Tags: categorical-data, linear-model, ordinal-data

I need to identify relationships between multiple 'counting' independent variables (representing numbers of amino acids in a protein sequence) and one ordered categorical dependent variable (an experimental outcome) which assumes values between 1 and 7.

The distribution of the dependent variable looks the following:
[image: Distribution of dependent variable.]

I know that for such cases linear regression models are not appropriate, but I'm under big time pressure and it would be a big plus if I can get something out of a linear model in a fast and dirty way.

Hence my questions:

**1) Do I have to expect biased coefficients even in the case I did not miss any relevant independent variable?**

**2) Is the 'real' standard error larger, smaller or unrelated to the one given during the model estimation?**

Below are the two diagnostic plots created in R.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: QQ plot.]
[image: Standardized residuals vs. fitted values.]

Comment: With an ordinal esponse variable with values from 1...7, a linear model coud work.  Your residuals are a bit skewed, though.  Did you try an ordinal regression model?  There is a CRAN package  ordinal.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried out `polr`, but got stuck with diagnosing the models as I'm not experienced with generalized linear models ... I will have a look at `ordinal`, but can you say anything about the impact of the skewed residuals? My situation is that **any reliable results** - even if they are only rough - I get now are very, very valuable, even if the underlying models are flawed!

Comment: OK. From your last plot, it seems you get no fitted values about 1 or 6, 7. If that is a problem, ordinal regression might be better. Or it might just be because those values 1,6,7 are few in the data.  Otherwise, your linear model might be OK.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me a lot! The exact categories of the dependent variable and their predictions are not so important, what matters to me is the influence of the amino acid numbers. Hence you helped me significantly in improving my feelings about the linear model :-)!